# Iterating along 2 lists at the same time in haskell (without resorting to zip)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have 2 lists:

```
[[1,2],[4,5]]
```

and

```
[0, 3]
```

and I'd like to turn it into

```
[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
```

I've created a function that does just that:

```
myFun xxs xs = map (\x -> (fst x):(snd x)) (zip xs xxs)
```

and it works. But I am still left wondering whether there might exist a better way to accomplish this without using the zip. Is there any?

Basically what I want to do is iterate along the 2 lists at the same time, something that I can't think of a way to do in Haskell without resorting to zip.

Thanks

Comment: `zipWith f xs ys = map (uncurry f) $ zip xs ys`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [zipWith](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/zipWith_f.html). For example:

```
zipWith (:) [0,3] [[1,2],[4,5]]
```

Gives:

```
[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Why is zip not an option?

Or should I say, zipWith.

```
zipWith (\x y -> x:y) xs xxs
```

Comment: It's not that it's not an option. I am just wondering if there are other ways of doing it.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh. That zipwith might just be what I was looking for!

Comment: `zipWith` is the intended way to join the elements of two lists using an arbitrary function. Any other method is basically reimplementing `zipWith`.

Comment: You can also do this with parallel list comprehension: `[a+b | a <- [1, 2, 3] | b <- [4, 5, 6]]`, which I think are still a non-standard extension, but GHC supports with -XParallelListComp.  That said, `zipWith (:)` is the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can move the zip into the type with `ZipList` from `Control.Applicative`:

```
myFun xxs xs = getZipList $ (:) <$> ZipList xs <*> ZipList xxs
```